# Custom mouse controls

Tags: camera, customization

I'm new to blender and I am having a hard time setting up my mouse camera controls properly.

I have set:

```
Selection to left mouse button. 
Set 3d cursor to middle mouse button.
Rotate view to right mouse button.
Move view (panning the camera) to button five.
```

Now everything works in object and edit mode, but as soon as I use the scale or grab (translate) tool I can no longer rotate or pan the camera. Right click actually cancels the tool. In knife mode I found a setting to disable right click cancel (which allows me to rotate), but I still cannot pan the camera.

Does anyone know how I can fix these? Its making it rally hard to practice.

Comment: It's not your custom keymap, it's a known limitation of Blender. You can't transform view while executing another operator and you can't execute other operators while transforming view.

Comment: Shoot. Ok well thanks for the info. At least now I wont waste anymore time digging though the menus.